# The HTTP request is not being executed in response - Flutter/Dart

Tags: http, flutter, dart

I'm trying to perform a request to a Web API written in C# (.NET Core). The endpoint runs a async function and return a JSON with result of operation.

In Dart I can't get the response. **then()** or **catchError()** just don't executes.

The endpoint get products in payload. When I send only one product I can get the response but when ai send two or more I can't.

The payload is:

```dart
http .post('http://192.168.0.10:5000/api/v1/oficina/dart',
                  body: jsonEncode({
                    "usuario": "edigleyssonsilva",
                    "senha": "123456",
                    "codEmp": 1,
                    "codFil": 1,
                    "produtos": [
                      {
                        "ccuRes": "160",
                        "codEmp": 1,
                        "codFil": 1,
                        "codPro": "570.0001",
                        "codTns": "90250",
                        "datPrv": "2020-02-17",
                        "datEme": "2020-02-17",
                        "qtdEme": 2
                      }
                    ]
                  }),
                  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
              .then((value) => print(value.body))
              .catchError((err) {
                print('Ocorreu um erro');
                print(err);
              });
```

I already tested the same endpoint with the same payload on Postman, Angular app and on a test file written in Dart and this works perfectly.

So, I have no idea why it doesn't work in Flutter

Comment: what do you mean by "but when ai send two or more I can't"?

Comment: The payload. The array **produtos** when I send one this works perfectly. If I send two more cacthError() or then() not works.

Comment: I think so. Can you show me where?

Comment: But this is the code snippet. Basically the same written in the test and it works. You said there was a bug I thought was in the request.

Comment: this is one request, you were talking about two?

Comment: I'm talking about payload. About the items on array.

Comment: ahh, I see it now, I got too little coffee maybe...

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear tell with the code you shared, either also share the code calling this function, but you can also try, with assigning your body to a Map object, and then encode it with json.encode, as jsonEncode was deprecated in new versions, though it works, but you should use the new way to encode it.
Also, you should use async-await while doing any asynchronous work.

```
Future<void> request() async {

 Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    };
Map body = {"usuario": "edigleyssonsilva",
                    "senha": "123456",
                    "codEmp": 1,
                    "codFil": 1,
                    "produtos": [
                      {
                        "ccuRes": "160",
                        "codEmp": 1,
                        "codFil": 1,
                        "codPro": "570.0001",
                        "codTns": "90250",
                        "datPrv": "2020-02-17",
                        "datEme": "2020-02-17",
                        "qtdEme": 2
                      }
                    ]};
final response = await http.post(url, 
                body: json.encode(body), 
                headers: headers,
              ).catchError((err) {
                print('Ocorreu um erro');
                print(err);
              });
print('Response: ${response.body}');
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But doesn't work! Tha backend runs the request normally (the request is sendind perfectly). The problem is that I can't get the response.

Comment: I have edited my answer, you can call your result after your request gets executed.

Comment: Yeah I saw. The problem persists. I used await too but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If this only happens when calling a service on localhost:
Change your url from `http://localhost:8080/bla` to
`http://10.0.2.2:8080/bla`.

The problem is that your emulator doesn't understand localhost, like your machine's localhost, so to access it you need to switch to  10.0.2.2